# Xcode not finding Swift packages

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I migrated from CocoaPods to Swift Package Manager on Xcode recently (version 14.2) and everything was working perfectly a few weeks ago.

All of a sudden this past weekend, the package manager can no longer locate any of the packages.

I've tried reseting package caches, deleting derived data, deleting caches manually, deleting packages & re-entering, etc. but I cannot get Xcode to reload the packages.

I tried upgrading to version 15.0 of Xcode and the same issue.

I checked my GitHub and I'm signed into Xcode with a working token.

I feel like there must be a setting in Xcode somewhere that's causing this new issue but I can't locate it or figure out.

Can anyone think of what to do?

Per photo, SPM has all of my packages loaded from before but on the bottom left, the version no longer shows up.  When I reset the package cache, the spinner wheel makes it look like it's loading but then ultimately times out and no files are in those folders.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out, answering for others facing the same issue.

One of the packages (google maps) only has version up to 7.3 (not 8.0!).

Xcode is somehow not smart enough to figure this out and by inputting a version that it cannot find in one package it ruins the connections for all other packages.  Updating this one package to 7.3 fixed all the other connections.

Comment: everything Apple does for developers is half-cooked. Thanks.